# 'Exec' parameter with 'echo' and 'awk' filter

Tags: shell, awk, exec, echo, ksh

There's this line I want to use in a ksh script :

```
find . -type f -exec echo "{} $comment" | awk '{printf "%-30s %s", $1, $2}' \;
```

Without the awk, this line is working great :

```
find . -type f -exec echo "{} $comment" \;
```

When I added the awk to make columns, I had this error :

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `;' for reading (No such file or directory)
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I don't find the good syntax. Do you, guys, have any idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a 2 things that I actually cannot understand.

1. What is `\;` stand for?
2. What is `-` for in `printf "%-30s %s", $1, $2`?

Anyway, try that.

```
$> find . -type f -exec echo "{} $comment" \; | awk '{printf "%30s %s\n", $1, $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks ! I put the awk filter after the `\;` and it works. The `-` is there to align the text on the left side.

Comment: `\;` is basically for `find` to enable it to distinguish the commands it is executing from its own arguments (`exec` in this case). The `-` in `"%-30s"` is for alignment. It specifies left adjustment of the output it is used for. :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 find . -type f -exec printf "%-30s %s\n" "{}" "$comment" \;
```